# Some Words not show when query in apache solr use facet

Tags: solr

I was query in solr use `http://localhost:8983/solr/matching/select?facet.field=content&facet=on&q=\*:\*` . And not all words not show. this is my key and value in solr

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "content":["Jakarta - KM Sinar Bangun tenggelam di Danau Toba, Sumut. Menteri Pariwisata Arief Yahya berharap, audit transportasi dan keamanan di sana diperketat.\n\n\"Pertama-tama kita berbelasungkawa atas KM Sinar Baru yang tenggelam di Danau Toba. Saya juga ikut memonitor dan apa yang sudah dilakukan rekan-rekan Basarnas sudah bagus,\" katanya di Balairung Soesilo Soedarman, Gedung Sapta Pesona, Jakarta, Kamis (21/6/2018) setelah acara Halal Bi Halal Kementerian Pariwisata.\n\nKM Sinar Bangun tenggelam di Danau Toba, Senin (18/6) sekitar pukul 17.30 WIB. Kapal tenggelam saat berlayar dari Pelabuhan Simanindo, Kabupaten Samosir, menuju Pelabuhan Tigaras, Kabupaten Simalungun.\n\nKorban hilang penumpang KM Sinar Bangun yang tenggelam berjumlah 186. Sebanyak 94 orang teridentifikasi, sedangkan 92 orang belum diketahui identitasnya.\n\n\"Kabarnya kapal itu over capacity atau tidak memenuhi spesifik teknis. Saya setuju. Ke depannya diaudit kepada semua kapal yang berlayar di Danau Toba,\" tegas Arief.\n\nDanau Toba merupakan salah satu 10 Destinasi Prioritas atau 10 Bali Baru. Maka itu, poin keamanan, keselamatan dan pelayanannya harus terus ditingkatkan. Agar tidak terulang lagi musibah Danau Toba.\n\n\"Kita harapkan akan lebih ketat dan selektif terutama saat hari-hari besar di sana. Nanti ketemu lagi di Natal dan Tahun Baru harus dipersiapkan lebih bagus,\" tutupnya. (aff/fay)\n"],
    "_version_":1603877168829431808},
  {
    "id":"2",
    "content":["Jakarta - KM Sinar Bangun tenggelam di Danau Toba, Sumut. Menteri Pariwisata Arief Yahya berharap, audit transportasi dan keamanan di sana diperketat.\n\n\"Pertama-tama kita berbelasungkawa atas KM Sinar Baru yang tenggelam di Danau Toba. Saya juga ikut memonitor dan apa yang sudah dilakukan rekan-rekan Basarnas sudah bagus,\" katanya di Balairung Soesilo Soedarman, Gedung Sapta Pesona, Jakarta, Kamis (21/6/2018) setelah acara Halal Bi Halal Kementerian Pariwisata.\n\nKM Sinar Bangun tenggelam di Danau Toba, Senin (18/6) sekitar pukul 17.30 WIB. Kapal tenggelam saat berlayar dari Pelabuhan Simanindo, Kabupaten Samosir, menuju Pelabuhan Tigaras, Kabupaten Simalungun.\n\nKorban hilang penumpang KM Sinar Bangun yang tenggelam berjumlah 186. Sebanyak 94 orang teridentifikasi, sedangkan 92 orang belum diketahui identitasnya.\n\n\"Kabarnya kapal itu over capacity atau tidak memenuhi spesifik teknis. Saya setuju. Ke depannya diaudit kepada semua kapal yang berlayar di Danau Toba,\" tegas Arief.\n\nDanau Toba merupakan salah satu 10 Destinasi Prioritas atau 10 Bali Baru. Maka itu, poin keamanan, keselamatan dan pelayanannya harus terus ditingkatkan. Agar tidak terulang lagi musibah Danau Toba.\n\n\"Kita harapkan akan lebih ketat dan selektif terutama saat hari-hari besar di sana. Nanti ketemu lagi di Natal dan Tahun Baru harus dipersiapkan lebih bagus,\" tutupnya. (aff/fay)\n"],
    "_version_":1603877168887103488}
```

and after query the result is :

```
"facet_counts":{
"facet_queries":{},
"facet_fields":{
  "content":[
    "10",2,
    "17",2,
    "18",2,
    "186",2,
    "2018",2,
    "21",2,
    "30",2,
    "6",2,
    "92",2,
    "94",2,
    "acara",2,
    "aff",2,
    "agar",2,
    "akan",2,
    "apa",2,
    "arief",2,
    "atas",2,
    "atau",2,
    "audit",2,
    "bagus",2,
    "balairung",2,
    "bali",2,
    "bangun",2,
    "baru",2,
    "basarnas",2,
    "belum",2,
    "berbelasungkawa",2,
    "berharap",2,
    "berjumlah",2,
    "berlayar",2,
    "besar",2,
    "bi",2,
    "capacity",2,
    "dan",2,
    "danau",2,
    "dari",2,
    "depannya",2,
    "destinasi",2,
    "di",2,
    "diaudit",2,
    "diketahui",2,
    "dilakukan",2,
    "diperketat",2,
    "dipersiapkan",2,
    "ditingkatkan",2,
    "fay",2,
    "gedung",2,
    "halal",2,
    "harapkan",2,
    "hari",2,
    "harus",2,
    "hilang",2,
    "identitasnya",2,
    "ikut",2,
    "itu",2,
    "jakarta",2,
    "juga",2,
    "kabarnya",2,
    "kabupaten",2,
    "kamis",2,
    "kapal",2,
    "katanya",2,
    "ke",2,
    "keamanan",2,
    "kementerian",2,
    "kepada",2,
    "keselamatan",2,
    "ketat",2,
    "ketemu",2,
    "kita",2,
    "km",2,
    "korban",2,
    "lagi",2,
    "lebih",2,
    "maka",2,
    "memenuhi",2,
    "memonitor",2,
    "menteri",2,
    "menuju",2,
    "merupakan",2,
    "musibah",2,
    "nanti",2,
    "natal",2,
    "orang",2,
    "over",2,
    "pariwisata",2,
    "pelabuhan",2,
    "pelayanannya",2,
    "penumpang",2,
    "pertama",2,
    "pesona",2,
    "poin",2,
    "prioritas",2,
    "pukul",2,
    "rekan",2,
    "saat",2,
    "salah",2,
    "samosir",2,
    "sana",2,
    "sapta",2]},
"facet_ranges":{},
"facet_intervals":{},
"facet_heatmaps":{}}
```

in the result "Sinar","tenggelam", "toba" and some word not show.
This is my field configuration

```
   <fieldType name="edgytext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" />
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```

So whats wrong with my query or solr field configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list of facets cuts off at 100 - all the words you are missing are after this cutoff point. The problem isn't that the values hasn't been indexed, it's that you're not retrieving them. [By default the `facet.limit` parameter is set to `100`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.limitParameter) - set it `-1` to return all terms for a field and their associated counts.

```
&facet=true&facet.field=content&facet.limit=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hi my suggestion is replace your field type edgytext with below defination.

```
<fieldType name="edgytext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" 
multiValued="true">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

If you want all words in with counts in facet then you need to StandardTokenizerFactory.

> What is solr.StandardTokenizerFactory ?
>
> It tokenizes on whitespace, as well as strips characters.

```
Example :
http://google.com/i+love+birds
```

would generate 6 tokens (separated by comma) -

```
 http,google.com,I,love,birds
```

> what is KeywordTokenizerFactory?

Keyword Tokenizer does not split the input at all.
No processing in performed on the string, and the whole string is treated as a single entity.
This doesn't actually do any tokenization. It returns the original text as one term.

Mainly used for sorting or faceting requirements, where you want to match the exact facet when filtering on multiple words and sorting as sorting does not work on tokenized fields.

Comment: The `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` attached splits the words into separate tokens, so although using a tokenizer would also be a solution, it isn't the cause of the missing facets. If the content weren't tokenized or split in any way, the result would be just one or two large tokens with an attached count.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i will try it.